# Get current displayed page on bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the bootstrap table to display my data.
I have added a column which displays edit button for each row.
when I click on the edit button, I display a bootstrap modal with data from that row in order to edit it.
I look for the ID of that record on the trigerring row in order to modify it using the following code:

```
$('#ModifyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  var GroupRowIndex = ($($(event.target)[0]).closest('tr')).index();
  if (GroupRowIndex >= 0) {
    GroupeId = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[GroupRowIndex].id_Groupe;
  }
});
```

This is working fine for me.
However, when I am working on a row in a different page than the first one, the index that I am working with is the one from the first page as it simply tells the row number on that page regardless of which page it is in.

Basically, I would like to have the page number that is currently displayed in order to work through how to get the correct index.
I have found events that are fired when I change the page such as: `'onPageChange'`
so I could potentially do as follows:

```
currentPageGlobalVar =  $('#table').bootstrapTable('onPageChange')
```

but I was wondering if there is a better solution that using the global variable (which I actually used to save the ID of the row triggering the modal for the edit action.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I was looking for:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('getOptions').pageNumber;
```

and to get the page size:

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable('getOptions').pageSize;
```